Lua scripting being used in mouse macro. (logitech)
I have a Lua script for Logitech G Hub that moves my mouse for me. It's set to use MB4 for that. I want to remap MB5 to press shift, mb4. But when I have the script running and press MB5, it only outputs shift being pressed.
The following script works perfectly as is (MB4 move mouse):
MoveAmount = -900
function OnEvent(event, arg)
  OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg)
  if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
    EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
  elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
    ReleaseMouseButton(4) -- to prevent it from being stuck on
  end

if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 4) then
    for x=1,10,1
    do
        MoveMouseRelative(MoveAmount, 0)
        Sleep(5)

But I want to use that in a macro, which isn't picking it up.
How can I bind this to a macro?
